# Required oracle Query to to display data in one single string

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query to display data .. where

A is link to B

B is link to C

C is link to D

D is link to E

In the same table in different column in same table as

col1 -   col2

A    -    B

B    -    C

C    -   D

D    -    E

I need it show data as E,D,C,B,A stating with E

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far..

Comment: Hi and welcome, please review how to ask a question especially the minimum reproducible example at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hierarchical query with `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( col1, col2 ) AS
SELECT 'A', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 'E' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH( col2, ',' ) || ',' || col1, 2 ) AS path
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH col2 = 'E'
CONNECT BY PRIOR col1 = col2;
```

**Output**:

> ```
> | PATH      |
> | :-------- |
> | E,D,C,B,A |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f4361feb831c023f4db411ae9f6201ba)*

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical Oracle hierarchical query.

To start with, consider the following query, that returns all the parents of the record whose `col2` has value `'E'`:

```
select col1, col2, level 
from mytable 
start with col2 = 'E' 
connect by prior col1 = col2;
```

Returns:

```
COL1 | COL2 | LEVEL
:--- | :--- | ----:
D    | E    |     1
C    | D    |     2
B    | C    |     3
A    | B    |     4
```

Now we can turn this to a subquery and use aggregate function `LISTAGG()` to generate the expected result:

```
select listagg(case when lvl = 1 then col2 || ',' end || col1, ',') 
    within group(order by lvl) seq
from (
    select col1, col2, level lvl 
    from mytable 
    start with col2 = 'E' 
    connect by prior col1 = col2
) x;
```

```
| SEQ       |
| :-------- |
| E,D,C,B,A |
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a76829248d37dee47d746a469365e3f6)**

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the hard-coded `'E,'` string in the outer query. Also, if you change the start to `F` (a value that doesn't exist) then this will return ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e0b9b1bf975bbc59d19b21b760b60c68)) an incorrect path as `LISTAGG` will always return a single row.

Comment: @MT0: thanks for your comment, I think I managed to take care of both points now. But I find your solution more elegant (and efficient) anyway!